# How to limit char array length in constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

Using Extended Embedded Cpp. How can I make this result in a compilation error in a release build:

```
Param okParam("Yeah!"); // this line should be ok
Param nOkParam("REEEEEEEEEEE"); // too big array, not ok. compiler error.
```

where:

```
int const c_max = 10;

template<int N>
struct Param
{
  char value[c_max];

  Param(char const (&p_value)[N])
  {
     memcpy(value, p_value, sizeof(p_value));
  }
};
```

I don't think you can template the constructor, so the entire struct needs to be templated, right?

---

I want this to provide a clean compiler error so that the person using this will notice it immediately.

Our version of extended embedded C++ doesn't provide any stl containers, I'm not sure if it's even possible.

I'm looking for some way to make the template result in a good compilation error. Sadly I can't use boost either, since the platform would not support it.

Comment: You can template the cosntructor, with N, and then you can use a static_assert.

Comment: I'll double check that I don't have static assert, but I don't think that this compiler supports it.

Comment: `char value[c_max];` is not valid, `c_max` needs to be a compile time constant. Also if your compiler does not support `static_assert` then it can be relatively easily implemented manually. See `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`

Comment: @VTT `int const c_max = 10;` *is* a constant expression.

Comment: @liliscent question has been edited, original version used non-static member field to hold array size.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't document the change, because it's not a major point in this question. Sorry for that confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically two solutions: [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) (C++98) or [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) (C++11):

### SFINAE

You can provide a constructor for `Param` only for char arrays less than a given size long. In C++98 this looks a bit ugly, but it works:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<bool b>
struct enable_if {};

template<>
struct enable_if<true>
{
    typedef int type;
};


template<std::size_t MAXSIZE>
struct Param
{
    template<std::size_t SIZE>
    explicit Param(
        char const (&input) [SIZE],
        std::size_t = sizeof(typename enable_if<SIZE < MAXSIZE>::type) // SFINAE at work
    ) { (void) input; }
};

int main()
{
    // "hello": char const[6], 6 < 7, OK
    Param<7> p1("hello");

    // "hello world": char const[12], 12 >= 7, KO
    Param<7> p2("hello world"); // ugly error here
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cca5dcbd95c52e3b)

### Assert (C++11 only)

Inside the constructor of `Param`, you can *check* if the supplied char array is too big and pop a readable error at compilation-time:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::size_t MAXSIZE>
struct Param
{
    template<std::size_t SIZE>
    explicit Param(char const (&input) [SIZE])
    { static_assert(sizeof(input) < MAXSIZE, "input is too big."); }
};

int main()
{
    // "hello": char const[6], 6 < 7, OK
    Param<7> p1("hello");

    // "hello world": char const[12], 12 >= 7, KO
    Param<7> p2("hello world"); // "error: static assertion failed: input is too big."
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a71252666019d8cd)

Comment: unfortunately, the OP can't use `static_assert()` or C++11 improvements

Comment: Any idea how to write std::enable_if_t by myself?

Comment: I feel stupid for not realizing how to make it now... well. Live and learn. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest way is to add a `static_assert`, using one of [the old C techniques for compile-time checks](/q/174356) if your implementation doesn't have `static_assert` yet:

```
#include <cstring>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#define static_assert(expr, message)                                    \
    int static_assert_(int (&static_assert_failed)[(expr)?1:-1])
#endif

template<int N>
struct Param
{
    static const int c_max = 10;
    static_assert(N < c_max, "Param string too long");
    char value[c_max];

    Param(char const (&p_value)[N])
    {
        std::memcpy(value, p_value, sizeof p_value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Param okParam("Yeah!"); // this line should be ok
    Param nOkParam("REEEEEEEEEEE"); // too big array, not ok. compiler error.
}
```

Comment: There's no tag for eecpp, it's not c++98 either. I told this critical information in the first sentence though.

Comment: Nice. Should it be [(expr)?0:-1]) If i want to support arrays of size 1.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d, no: that's there to generate an error when `expr` is false (remember, in this case, `expr` expands to `N < c_max`).  Some compilers permit zero-sized arrays (as a non-standard extension), so using a negative value to trigger the failure is more robust.

Comment: Right, I read it wrong, yes. You are creating an array there. I misread how the error was being generated. I see it now.

Comment: Actually, it declares *a function* that takes a (valid or erroneous) array reference as parameter.